# grails push notification from one user to another

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

how can I send push notification from one user to another
for example I want to run my application then I open it from chrome with user1 and firefox with user2
and then send a push notification from one user to another

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Web Push technology. I've recently used it, there is a [Java library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java) for it. Relatively easy to integrate and works quite stable.